# Swift: get more detailed info on function parameter type error

Tags: xcode, swift, llvm

I'm using Xcode 6.3.1 and Swift.

When a function with multiple parameter get some error on parameter type, it's hard to know which argument is wrong.

For example, `CGBitmapContextCreate()`, this code:

```
let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, UInt(size.width), UInt(size.height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

will produce an error like this:

```
MyFile.swift:23:19: Cannot invoke 'CGBitmapContextCreate' with an argument list of type '(nil, UInt, UInt, Int, Int, CGColorSpace, CGBitmapInfo)'
```

By comparing the document and my argument list carefully, I can find that it is the 2nd and 3rd arguments, which should be Int.

Is there any way to make the compiler more smarter on this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably that the online documentation you are looking at for `CGBitmapContextCreate` is wrong based on the definition you are actually accessing when you are compiling.

The last parameter needs to be of type `UInt32` , and `CGBitmapInfo` is returning a `CGBitmapInfo` object. That is why the compiler is erring. You are passing in the wrong type of parameters. You can even right click the function and click "see definition", this will verify what I am saying.

Try instead, passing in `CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue` directly, as it is the UInt32 that is being looked for.

Example Solution:

```
let colorSpace:CGColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, UInt(size.width), UInt(size.height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

You'll find that you will be able to compile the source, and get the expected result. Note that you can still apply any bitwise operations you want to on this value.

PS: I had the same issue you were having, and was amply frustrated when I couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
    let width = CGImageGetWidth(image)
    let height = CGImageGetHeight(image)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    let bitsPerComponent :Int = 8
    let pixels = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(malloc(width*height*4))
    var context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo())
```

Comment: Unless you later free `pixels`, this leaks the buffer. It also doesn't have the same functionality as the OP's code (it treats the alpha channel differently).